# How to get the line spacing of NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

How can I get the line spacing of NSTextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get `defaultParagraphStyle` of your NSTextView.

```
myTextView.defaultParagraphStyle.lineSpacing
```